# Why does a macro that uses "let" expand differently from one that doesn't?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, let

I am new to Lisp and I am reading through Doug Hoyte's Let Over Lambda and he presents Paul Graham's `nif` macro in Chapter 3.  I was playing around with that and made these two macros:

```
(defmacro niffy (expr pos zero neg)
  `(cond ((plusp ,expr) ,pos)
         ((zerop ,expr) ,zero)
         (t ,neg)))

(defmacro niffy2 (expr pos zero neg)
  `(let ((x ,expr))
     (cond ((plusp x) ,pos)
           ((zerop x) ,zero
            (t ,neg)))))
```

When I do `(macroexpand '(niffy2 10 "positive" "zero" "negative"))`, I get what I expect: `(LET ((X 10)) (COND ((PLUSP X) "positive") ((ZEROP X) "zero" (T "negative"))))`

But when I do `(macroexpand '(niffy 10 "positive" "zero" "negative"))` I just get the evaluated form `"positive"`.  Which confuses me because in `niffy`, `cond` is backquoted, so I thought that meant it wouldn't be evaluated.  Evaluating both `niffy` and `niffy2` without the macro expansion both work exactly as I expect, returning "positive", "zero", and "negative" for positive, zero, and negative values respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `cond` is a macro.  Try running the following:

```
(macroexpand
 '(cond ((plusp 10) "positive")
        ((zerop 10) "negative")
        (t "zero")))
```

In SBCL, I get this:

```
(IF (PLUSP 10)
    (PROGN "positive")
    (COND ((ZEROP 10) "negative") (T "zero")))
T
```

In CLISP, I get this:

```
"positive" ;
T
```

While I can understand CLISP's behavior, it seems a bit needless, since the optimization could more easily be handled after macroexpansion.

(Note that you should ordinarily prefer the version with `let` because it doesn't evaluate its argument multiple times.)

Comment: Ah okay, I am using clisp.  So has clisp just compiled `cond` or something?  Also, now I see if I do `macroexpand-1 niffy` I get the behavior I expect.

Comment: It looks like the macro for `cond` in CLISP is just doing some optimization.  Compilation would result in different output, I think CLISP has a compiler with byte code output.  (CLISP is defunct anyway, by the way)

Answer (score 1):

**Your code has an error**:

```
(defmacro niffy2 (expr pos zero neg)
  `(let ((x ,expr))
     (cond ((plusp x) ,pos)
           ((zerop x) ,zero              <- missing parenthesis
            (t ,neg)))))                 <- T is not a function
```

Test:

```
(defun test (x)
  (niffy2 x "positive" "zero" "negative"))
```

The compiler complains:

```
The following function is undefined:
T which is referenced by TEST
```

It should be:

```
(defmacro niffy2 (expr pos zero neg)
  `(let ((x ,expr))
     (cond ((plusp x) ,pos)
           ((zerop x) ,zero)
           (t ,neg))))
```

> But when I do (macroexpand '(niffy 10 "positive" "zero" "negative")) I just get the evaluated form "positive".

Since you call for a macro expansion, it can't be evaluated. It must be an effect of the macro expander in that implementation.

Note that `MACROEXPAND` is an iterative process. The form will be expanded. The result form then could be another macro form. It will be expanded, too. And again. Again. Until the result form is not a macro form. Note that this does not traverse the subforms. It's strictly doing iterative macro expansion of the top form.

**Use `MACROEXPAND-1`**

So if you want to see the effects of only your macro, call `MACROEXPAND-1`. This function will expand exactly once.

```
CL-USER 23 > (macroexpand-1 '(niffy 10 "positive" "zero" "negative"))
(COND ((PLUSP 10) "positive")
      ((ZEROP 10) "zero")
      (T "negative"))

CL-USER 24 > (macroexpand-1 '(COND ((PLUSP 10) "positive")
                                   ((ZEROP 10) "zero")
                                   (T "negative")))
(IF (PLUSP 10)
  (PROGN "positive")
  (IF (ZEROP 10)
     (PROGN "zero")
     (PROGN "negative")))
T
```

Comment: It's true that `t` is not a function, but that's not an error, because it's not being used as a function (at least, when the missing parenthesis is added).

Comment: @DietrichEpp: The Lisp system will not know that the parentheses are placed wrong. It will complain about the function application.

Comment: But as a human, we know that there is only one error in the code: the missing parenthesis.  Whether the Lisp system is sophisticated enough to figure this out is another matter.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I'm not sure how many people can easily find that, looking at the code. If later the Lisp system complains. It complains about the function call - that's why I mentioned it. One then has to work back to find the reason why T was used as a function.

Comment: Right, but you've figured out where the actual error is.  While it is worth mentioning that the Lisp system will probably complain that `t` is not a function, and it's worth explaining that this is caused by missing parenthesis, and it is worth teaching people how to figure out errors from diagnostic messages, there is still only one error: the missing parenthesis.